# Match the line after delimiter and shorter than 9

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

me and regex never get along 
i get every day an email from my supervisor 
contains about 1000+ lines need to be sorted 
its like :

name|code

the goal is to separate them to 2 files

**example :**

- Garry Cooper|abc123h1n1
- Andy Morray|abcd
- John Travolta|123567
- Simon Person | abcd1

**what i do**

i look after | character 
i remove the whole line :
if code contains numbers only 
and or contains letters only
and or is shorter than 9

the example list becomes :

Garry Cooper|abc123h1n1

this steps i do them daily sometimes i get 2000 lines :/ real pain

i used to work with regex in notepad++ 
but i cant found the match for this one 
i am not very bad also in php 
help me please

***UPDATE 01 :*** 
regex found (?i)^[^|]*\|\h*[a-z\d]{0,8}$\R?
Current question : 
writting a small php script or maybe reusable classes

1. **interface:**

submit the data from text box (html form) or from txt file

2. **processing :**

lines that match the regex downloadable in txt file.
others in a files

3. **output:**

2 links of the files

Thank u all for your help in advance

Comment: i am trying to find regex for np++ so i can remove bulk lines matchs the conditions mentionned

Comment: So, you still use some regex, don't you? Please share

Comment: i used to use some simple expression like \something(.*)

Comment: Please add that to the question (edit your post) and describe what does not work right. And please check if [`(?i)^[^|]*\|\h*[a-z\d]{0,8}$\R?`](https://regex101.com/r/rK9tS9/1) works for you.

Comment: @stribizhev Off topic but why do you post this as a comment and not an answer? Still trying to understand SO. Is this some sort of etiquette?

Comment: @buckley Posted as an answer if you insist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use a greedy dot matching with `.*` you do not check the length. It can be checked with the limiting quantifier. To match just 0 to 8 symbols, you can use `{0,8}`. All but `|` can be matched with `[^|]*` negated character class.

Use

```
(?i)^[^|]*\|\h*[a-z\d]{0,8}$\R?
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK9tS9/1) (note that `gm` flags are used by default in Notepad++ regex-based search and replace).

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^|]*` - zero or more symbols other than a pipe
- `\|` - a literal pipe symbol
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `[a-z\d]{0,8}` - letters a to z and A to Z (due to `(?i)` case insensitive modifier) or digits, zero to 8 occurrences
- `$` - end of line and
- `\R?` - one or zero (otpional) line break.

[image]